# Can python throw a "stack overflow" error?

Tags: python, stack-overflow

**Can python have a `stack overflow` error?**

Recently I was just letting my mind wander when I came across the question: "can python get the `stack overflow` error? Does anyone have any answers?

I searched for the answer but only found java answers. I have used java but its just not my question:

1. [What is a StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror)
2. https://rollbar.com/blog/how-to-fix-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-in-java/

**My Reasoning**

I initially thought no because python just... works most of the time (like passing an int for a string). It also doesn't have stacks (to my knowledge). But I wasn't sure. Here I am.

Comment: Of course it has a stack, that's how function calls are implemented. If you recurse too deeply you get a stack overflow error.

Comment: My brain just connected why stack trace is called stack trace...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sure it can**

the following code will cause a seg fault:

```py
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10_000_000)

def foo():
    foo()
```

On Mac OS, this throws:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Which is caused by a stack overflow.

Comment: Whoa, cool. I had no idea about `sys.setrecursionlimit`.

Comment: same! @user17242583

Answer (score 2):

You can, if your recursion limit is too high:

```
def foo():
    return foo()


>>> foo()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  .......
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
>>>
```

The default recursion limit is `10**3` (verifiable via **`sys.getrecursionlimit`**), but you can change it using **`sys.setrecursionlimit`**:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**8)

def foo():
    foo()
```

but doing so could be dangerous -- the standard limit is a little conservative, but Python stackframes can be quite big.

Comment: If the recursion limit is too high the error will actually say `MemoryError: Stack overflow`

Comment: Also, I believe the limit is `10**3` not `10**4`. Check with `sys.getrecursionlimit()`

Answer (score 0):

By default, Python's recursion limit is 10**3, theoretically if you were to pass this then you would be given a [`RecursionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RecursionError).

You can even reduce the recursion limit using [`setrecursionlimit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) to make this happen more quickly.

Comment: You are the second to mention `10**4` as the default limit, however I suspect it is an implementation detail. I get `10**3` as the default in 64-bit CPython 3.8.5 on 64-bit Win 11

Comment: Your right, the default is actually 1000. (Checked with `sys.getrecursionlimit()`)